# JavaScript create arrays from JSON data

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've been a bit stuck on this for a bit and would love some pointers.

I have a data structure like so:

```
var data = {
        "banana": [{
                nameOfItem: "Mexico",
                id: 1
            },
            {
                nameOfItem: "France",
                id: 2
            }],
        "mango": [{
                nameOfItem: "Italy",
                id: 3
            },
            {
                nameOfItem: "Bulgaria",
                id: 4
            }]
    };
```

I want to split that data into separate arrays that have the name of the fruit as the name of the array and the name/id of the country as values in that array so it would look something like:

```
var banana = [
  [1, "Mexico"],
  [2, "France"]
];

var mango = [
  [3, "Italy"],
  [4, "Bulgaria"]
];
```

The problem I am having is accessing the nameOfItem and id parameters for each object. Also I do not know the order or the names of the fruits that will come back from the data or the number of countries that will be coming back for each fruit as well, so I cannot hard code it. Currently I have this code that returns me the name of the fruits:

```
for (var i=0; i < Object.keys(data).length; i++) {
        var nameOfFruit = Object.keys(data)[i];
        console.log(nameOfFruit);
    }
```

[Link to JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/823rphd8/)

**EDIT 1:**
The idea behind this is to populate 2 dropdown menus with that data. First dropdown would be name of fruit (banana / mango) second one will change based on what is selected. I am open to suggestions.

But from here on I'm not sure how to proceed. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you for taking the time to help.

Comment: Are you sure you want to use `array`s for the values of `banana` and `mango`? IMO better use `object`s

Comment: @BenKolyaMansley yes you can with the window object

Comment: use window[nameOfFruit ] = {}

Comment: I am open to suggestions. Basically I have 2 dropdowns that need populated based on those items. First Dropdown would be name of value (banana/ mango) second one will change based on what is selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`data[nameOfFruit]` returns an array of objects. If you iterate over that array, you have access to nameOfItem

```
var items = data[nameOfFruit];
items.forEach(item => { console.log(item.nameOfItem)});
```

see here: https://jsfiddle.net/823rphd8/7/

Answer (score 0):

Something like this could work:

```
for (var key in data) {
    window[key] = data[i];
}
```

Iterate over your object and for each key create a variable and assign the object entry to the new variable.

Answer (score 0):

based on your code you can  simply do this as well

console.log(data[nameOfFruit]);

Answer (score 0):

use `window` to store vairables

```
   for (var i=0; i < Object.keys(data).length; i++) {
        var nameOfFruit = Object.keys(data)[i];
        window[nameOfFruit] = [];

        for(var j = 0 ; j < data[nameOfFruit].length; j++){
            var currentItem = data[nameOfFruit][j];
             window[nameOfFruit].push([currentItem.id,currentItem.nameOfItem])
        }
        console.log(nameOfFruit);
    }

console.log(banana)
console.log(mango)
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7dLncqob/

Answer (score 0):

A solution that mutate the original array:

```js
var data = {
        "banana": [{
                nameOfItem: "Mexico",
                id: 1
            },
            {
                nameOfItem: "France",
                id: 2
            }],
        "mango": [{
                nameOfItem: "Italy",
                id: 3
            },
            {
                nameOfItem: "Bulgaria",
                id: 4
            }]
    };

Object.keys(data).forEach(key => {
    data[key] = data[key].map(val => Object.values(val));
});
console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```js
var data = {
        "banana": [{
                nameOfItem: "Mexico",
                id: 1
            },
            {
                nameOfItem: "France",
                id: 2
            }],
        "mango": [{
                nameOfItem: "Italy",
                id: 3
            },
            {
                nameOfItem: "Bulgaria",
                id: 4
            }]
    };
    
let {banana : banana, mango: mango} = data;
banana = banana.map(e => [e.nameOfItem, e.id]);
mango = mango.map(e => [e.nameOfItem, e.id]);
console.log(banana, mango);
```

Answer (score 0):

An ES6 based solution - [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) the object to a new object with the original [keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys), but with [mapped](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) content for each key, then [destructure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) the keys to variables.

```js
var data = {
  "banana": [{
      nameOfItem: "Mexico",
      id: 1
    },
    {
      nameOfItem: "France",
      id: 2
    }
  ],
  "mango": [{
      nameOfItem: "Italy",
      id: 3
    },
    {
      nameOfItem: "Bulgaria",
      id: 4
    }
  ]
};

const { banana, mango } = Object.keys(data).reduce((o, k) =>
  (o[k] = data[k].map(({ id, nameOfItem }) => [id, nameOfItem]), o), {});
  
console.log(banana);

console.log(mango);
```